# LinearRegression Predict: No applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.Frame"

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have my data (currently dummy data):

```
data_for_prediction <- original_data[,c(1,3)]
```

*if you want to reproduce the issues the following is enough for this error:*

```
data_for_prediction <- data.frame(
  diff = c(1,2,3),
  f.mean_slope = c (1,2,3)
)
```

which consists of only two rows: "diff" (Y) and "f.mean_slope" (x)

then I sample the whole thing:

```
set.seed(101)
trainingRowIndex <- sample(1:nrow(data_for_prediction), 0.8*nrow(data_for_prediction))
trainingData <- data_for_prediction[trainingRowIndex, ]  
testData  <- data_for_prediction[-trainingRowIndex, ]
```

After that I create a fit:

```
model_fit <- lm(diff ~ ., data = trainingData, method = "model.frame")
```

And when I now try to predict something:

```
newdata <- data.frame(
  f.mean_slope = c(1,2,3)
)

distPred <- predict(model_fit, newdata)
```

And R Studio then just return the error message:

> Error in UseMethod("predict"): No applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.Frame"

Which drives me nuts, since I've searched tons of questions of the internet with a somewhat similar problem, but none worked...

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you used:

```
model_fit <- lm(diff ~ ., data = trainingData, method = "model.frame")
class(model_fit)
[1] "data.frame"
```

The above gives you the model matrix used to fit the data.

You can do instead:

```
model_fit <- lm(diff ~ ., data = trainingData,model=TRUE)
newdata <- data.frame(
  f.mean_slope = c(1,2,3)
)

distPred <- predict(model_fit, newdata)
```

And the model matrix can be found in `model_fit$model`

Comment: Nice works again, but then again.. not. I did this because I have some columns, that have overall simular values in it. So without the 'method = "model.frame" I'm getting a 'contrasts can only be applied to factors with 2 or more levels'. Is there a way to fix both?

Comment: Can you provide your data? You get that error because one of your predictors has only 1 levels

Comment: sure, thx for the help: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi0ebxzw9s2d07m/Original_Data.csv?dl=0

Comment: at the start I remove some columns, because they are not needed for the prediction process: data_for_prediction <- route[,c(7,13:ncol(route))]

DIFF <- Y, and all the others are potential features

Comment: your column date is causing the problem. there's one 1 value in there

Comment: and also, you have some columns where each entry is a level, for example, f.autocorrelation.lag2.string_fd_sumv, you cannot fit that.. remove those columns

Comment: Removed all those columns and changed all NA values to 0 and now it works. THANKS A LOT!